# Twitpic Error - Invalid Username and Password

Tags: android, twitter

I am using twitpic library to post an image on the twitter but i m getting - invalid twitpic username and password error.
Is there any solution to this??
What is the username and password of witpic. I am simply using my Twitter id and password in place of it.

Here's my code

```
// Create file
    File picture = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/image.jpg");
    if(picture.exists())
    {
        System.out.println("Picture accesseds");
    }

    // Create TwitPic object and allocate TwitPicResponse object
    TwitPic tpRequest = new TwitPic("gauravarora90", "gaurav");
    TwitPicResponse tpResponse = null;

    // Make request and handle exceptions                           
    try {
            tpResponse = tpRequest.uploadAndPost(picture, "Hello World!!!");
    } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TwitPicException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }


    // If we got a response back, print out response variables
    if(tpResponse != null) {         
           tpResponse.dumpVars();
           System.out.println(tpResponse.getStatus());
           if(tpResponse.getStatus().equals("ok")){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Photo posted on Twitter.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //picture.delete();
           }
     }
```

Kindly help me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try this code :

```
ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();

             cb.setOAuthConsumerKey(TwitterClass.CONSUMER_KEY);
             cb.setOAuthConsumerSecret(TwitterClass.CONSUMER_SECRET);
             cb.setOAuthAccessToken(tw.getAccessToken());
            AccessToken a = new AccessToken(tw.getAccessToken(),tw.getSecretToken());


             TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
                t4jTwitter = tf.getInstance();

                t4jTwitter.setOAuthAccessToken(a);

              Configuration conf = new ConfigurationBuilder()                 
                    .setOAuthConsumerKey(TwitterClass.CONSUMER_KEY) 
                    .setOAuthConsumerSecret(TwitterClass.CONSUMER_SECRET) 
                    .setOAuthAccessToken(tw.getAccessToken()) 
               .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(tw.getSecretToken()) 
                    .build(); 

                OAuthAuthorization auth = new OAuthAuthorization (conf, conf.getOAuthConsumerKey (), conf.getOAuthConsumerSecret (),
                        new AccessToken (conf.getOAuthAccessToken (), conf.getOAuthAccessTokenSecret ()));

               ImageUpload upload = ImageUpload.getTwitpicUploader (TWITPIC_KEY, auth);

                try {
                      //  String    url = upload.upload(new File("/mnt/sdcard/download/3029302084159350163.jpg"));


                                                //result = 1;


                        URL myfileUrl=new URL(strFilePath);

                        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) myfileUrl
                        .openConnection();
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.connect();
                InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();


                //   String url = upload.upload(new File("/mnt/sdcard/download/3029302084159350163.jpg"), StaticData.strTwitte);


                   String   url = upload.upload(StaticData.strTwitte, is);

                   System.out.println("Image url"+url);
                        System.out.println("Image uploaded");
                        result_img=1;
                        twitter4j.Status status = t4jTwitter.updateStatus(StaticData.strTwitte+"\n"+url);
                        int statusId = (int)status.getId();

                            //Log.d(TAG, "Image uploaded, Twitpic url is " + url);          
                        } catch (Exception e) {        
                            //Log.e(TAG, "Failed to send image");
                              result_img=0;
                              System.out.println("Failed to send image");
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
```

Comment: Good. You replied really very very fast.. Great and Thanks

Comment: actually some one refer me this post tomorrow ,because i did that task by using this code ,i did't seen this post earlier.